# Query All Subdocument in MongoDB

Tags: php, mongodb

I have document like this:

```
  {
     author: "ABC1",
     text:"this is a Post",
     details: {
        time: "14/05/2015",
        Edit: "none"
     },
     comments: [
         { 
               comment_text: "Hello",
                user: "alan",
                  time:"20/05/2014 20:44" 
           }, 
         { 
                comment_text: "Hi Every One",
                 user: "bob",
                  time:"20/05/2014 20:44"
          },
         { 
                 comment_text: "Good morning , Alan", 
                 user: "Alan",
                 time:"20/05/2014 20:44"
           },
         { 
                    comment_text: "I'm bob",
                    user: "bob", 
                    time:"20/05/2014 20:44"
            },
              ],
     category: "IT"
   }
```

i want to Querying all Subdocument which have user:"bob"
Example in PHP:
db.posts.find(array("comments.user"=>"bob");

I know this Syntax will not work for me.
And If the syntax is true, the Find Operations will show as:

```
                { 
                   comment_text: "I'm bob",
                   user: "bob", 
                   time:"20/05/2014 20:44" 
                },
                { 
                  comment_text: "Hi Every One",
                   user: "bob",
                  time:"20/05/2014 20:44" 
                },
```

How can I change Document Schema to do that?

Comment: what exactly you want to find comments.user = 'bob' ? and only shows user `bob` data I think this should be solve using aggregation.

Answer (score 2):

Yo don't need change Document Schema, you can find comments from Bob with aggregation:

```js
db.posts.aggregate([
  {$unwind:"$comments"},
  {$project:
     {"comment_text":"$comments.comment_text",
     "user":"$comments.user",
     "time":"$details.time",
     _id:0}
   },
   {$match:{"user":"bob"}}
 ])
```

Comment: I would also suggest putting an initial `$match` for `user : "bob"`. It's ultimately redundant, but putting an initial match will allow you to use an index and reduce the number of documents that need to be processed by the rest of the pipeline.